Probably not the first Tattoo translation request
I'm looking to get a memorial tattoo for my brother and would like to use the phrase "time of death" in Latin, which will be followed by the time and date. Google says "tempus mortis" but I want to try to get some advice first.
Any advice is appreciated!

The usual way to express a date of death in Latin is to say Obiit [diem suum], "he met [his day]", followed by the date or (more often) preceeded by the date. More commonly, the diem suum is dropped as being understood. This Latin usage has been carried wholesale into English, so much so that a list of death dates is referred to as an "obituary."
Or, if you prefer, you can take a page from Ecclesiastes, "To every thing there is a season, and a time to every purpose under the heaven: A time to be born, and a time to die..." The latin renders a time to die as tempus moriendi. (A time to be born is tempus nascendi, and so on.) "Tempus moriendi:" followed by the date might serve your purpose.
If you are going to spell out the date in Latin, be sure to put it in the ablative case to go with obiit or in the nominative case to go with tempus.
